# Linux Live CD crash after GRUB selection

Tags: linux, boot, system-installation, grub, livecd

I'm running on a fairly old HP Pavilion x360 - 13-a110dx (ENERGY STAR) with the newest BIOS firmware available. It has Intel HD 5500 graphics and 4 GB RAM. I'm currently trying to install ANY linux distribution to it from USB -- I can boot into the live USB just fine, however, whether I try to "Try it Without Installing" or "Install" it just goes to a black screen. Both UEFI and CSM mode do this. In CSM mode I can get to the purple screen where I select nomodeset etc, then it goes to splash screen for a hot minute and then to a black screen with a white pointer that freezes. I do not want to keep anything on my Hard Drive currently.

- Ubuntu
- Manjaro
- Arch

All of these do the same thing: black screen.

I have tried in boot options:

- nomodeset
- text mode
- various combinations of acpi="something"
- attempting to get to TTY via keyboard shortcuts

I have seen the megapost about this issue with all the workarounds and none of them have worked.

Comment: The closest relevant finding from my side is [this dated thread on Arch Linux Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=184117). That has mention of the boot option `acpi_osi="!Windows 2013"` which seems to agree with [this dated post on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/655135). Besides this, I am out of idea.

Comment: @clearkimura Thank you very much for the suggestion, it didn't seem to work, but I eventually did get it to work with the following options added in place of "quiet splash ---" "acpi=off nomodeset debug="

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I fixed it --

Upon booting the Ubuntu Live CD I had to changed the Linux boot parameter to have `acpi=off nomodeset debug=`. I believe this was overkill as to boot Ubuntu I had to just use `acpi=off`.

Now -- this would disable all of my acpi so I had no battery stats and my computer thought it was in airplane mode -- no good. Eventually I followed a step by step guide to determine why acpi was the issue, turns out it wasn't.

All I ended up having to do was add to my boot parameters `acpi_osi=` because this HP BIOS is a little funky -- this solved all of my issues.

Comment: +1 for your effort. Debian 8 Live had even more boot options: `noapic noapm nodma nomce nolapic nomodeset nosmp nosplash`, which is the longest "failsafe" boot option I have seen so far.